# Dropdown lists first option to be null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I Have a dropdownlist that allows you to selcect an exsiting Driver ID. when the page loads the first Driver ID is already selected and I would rather allow the Driver ID dropdownlist to first have a null value selected when the page loads. How will I do this?
This is my Driver ID view:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DriverID, "Driver Cell", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("DriverID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "box" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DriverID)
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: How are you populating the contents of the dropdownlist?

Comment: Stop using `DropDownList()` and start using the strongly typed `DropDownListFor(m => m.DriverID, Model.DriverList, "Please select", new { @class = "box" })` method where you model has a property `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DriverList` (or alternatively use `ViewBag`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
@Html.DropDownList("DriverID", null, "Select a driver", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "box" })
```

but this dropdown will be empty since you are passing `null` as `SelectList`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the asp-for tag helper with a SelectListItem list

Then this is what you write in your form in the view

```
<select asp-for="(Whatever the value is associated to)" asp-items="The List<SelectListItem> list">
    <option disabled selected>---Select---</option> 
<!-- This line will go to the top of the dropdown list -->
</select>
```

This will create a dropdown list where by default nothing is selected and this default value will be null

You can also refer to this other post on stack overflow:

[Set Default/Null Value with Select TagHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845786/set-default-null-value-with-select-taghelper)