# Set Default/Null Value with Select TagHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

In asp.net mvc you can use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, ViewBag.Category as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "-- SELECT --", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Using asp.net 5, how do I include the default or null value **(-- SELECT --)**  in a taghelper:

```
<select asp-for="Category" asp-items="@ViewBag.Category"  class="form-control"></select>
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can just insert an option item inside the select:

```
<select asp-for="Category" asp-items="@ViewBag.Category"  class="form-control">
    <option disabled selected>--- SELECT ---</option>
</select>
```

The `disabled` keyword in the code above means that the "--- SELECT ---" row cannot be picked again once a choice has been selected in the list. If you want the user to be able to blank the selection again (i.e. if it's bound to a nullable field) then just omit disabled.

Comment: I needed to set the option's value to an empty string to allow the user to null out the underlying nullable int field: <option value="">None</option>

Comment: And if you don't want disabled option to show in the drop-down list, you can style it to display none.

Comment: For nullable columns the default option should have value="" otherwise the model won't bind

Answer (score 8):

If you want to store value null to database then use 
`<option selected value="">Full Access</option>`

Comment: what if I need it to be null? if default option is submitted, I want it to be null instead of empty string.

Comment: This is the 2nd half of the answer (if you need to support nullable navigation properties, and not only have a header on the Select indicating "Please select a value")

Answer (score 2):

If you use asp-items for your model , It uses value 0 for selected item , If you have tag `<option>` with your default string without value ,

You must use a loop for `<option>` and put your default option out of loop.
This is an example for .Net Core using asp-items:

```
<select asp-for="DepartmentUnit" asp-items="@Model.DepartmentUnits" class="form-control"></select>
```

and Now this is another example for using loop:

```
<select>
<option val="">--Select--</option>
foreach(item in Model.DepartmentUnits)
{<option val="@item.val">@item.title</option>}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer by Matt:

```
    <select asp-for="Category" asp-items="@ViewBag.Category"  class="form-control">
        <option disabled selected>--- SELECT ---</option>
    </select>
```

also works with validation. Probably due to the option being `disabled` it seems not to be a valid selection.

btw.: this also works with MVC Core 3 ;-)