# Get a default NULL value from DropDownList in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am creating a **Trailer** for existing **Driver** (that can be selected from Drop Down list).

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Driver.driverID, (SelectList)ViewBag.DriverID, "-- Please Select -- ", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

For CREATE function it works perfectly.

```
//Create Get
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.DriverID = new SelectList(db.Drivers, "driverID", "driverFullName");
    return View();
}
```

For EDIT function (edit trailers number and leave the driver *NULL*) it does not work.

```
//Edit Get
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
     if (id == null)
     {
         return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
     }
     Trailer trailer = db.Trailers.Find(id);
     if (trailer == null)
     {
         return HttpNotFound();
     }
     ViewBag.DriverID = new SelectList(db.Drivers.ToList(), "driverID", "driverFullName");
     return View(trailer);
}
```

I have the *-- Please Select --* on the drop down list as a *first empty value*. 
How could I put a *NULL* value on this first empty value (so the trailer would have *NO* driver selected) from drop down list?

Comment: Please show us Create and Edit actions in your controller and how you populate ViewBag.DriverID.

Comment: why you want `null`?

Comment: If --Please Select-- was selected that means its NULL right? Why you want null?

Comment: --Please Select-- is just an empty slot. I want a NULL for the trailer none driver be selected.

Comment: can you provide Drivers model and you want to select   --Please Select--  will will return null ? but you cant submit when its --Please Select--  right?

Comment: Yes, that is right

Comment: and you want Driver.driverID to return null instead of 0 ? or you want to show empty list of drivers in edit ?

Comment: only when --Please Select-- to return null

Comment: but when trying to save, this line appears "The driverID field is required."

Comment: can you show Drivers model?

Comment: Drivers Model has this `public virtual ICollection<Trailer> Trailers { get; set; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is because your `driverID` property in `Drivers` class is not `nullable ?` that is why when you select `-- Please Select --`  it gives validation message `The driverID field is required` so you should set `driverID` to `nullable` like

```
public int? driverID {get;set;}
```

now its default value will be `null` when you select `-- Please Select --`

**Edit**

another way is to add a default object manually like

in view

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Driver.driverID, (SelectList)ViewBag.DriverID, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

and in edit action

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
     if (id == null)
     {
         return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
     }
     Trailer trailer = db.Trailers.Find(id);
     if (trailer == null)
     {
         return HttpNotFound();
     }

     var list = db.Drivers.ToList();
     list.Insert(0, new Drivers() {driverFullName = "-- Please Select --"});
     ViewBag.DriverID = new SelectList(list, "driverID", "driverFullName"); //showing the list of drivers on edit page
     return View(trailer);
}
```

Comment: This is my Trailer Model class. I have it int? 
`public class Trailer
    {
        public int trailerID { get; set; }

        public int? DriverID { get; set; }
        public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: It was like this from the beginning. I had it from before. It doesnot help

Comment: you are using Driver.driverID in code so it should be in driver class

Comment: but driverID in Driver class is a primary key

Comment: are you using view model or domain model?

Comment: The key field 'driverID' cannot have a value of null. A non-null value is required for the key fields defined on type 'Driver'

Comment: you should not change domain model instead create a view model and make changes in them

Comment: i think domain model

Comment: oh, so the model was the problem?! I'll try that, thank you!!

Comment: let me add another example

Comment: i have added another method try that

Answer (score 1):

When using the Tag Helpers in ASP.NET Core the following snippet might help:

```
<select asp-for="DriverId" asp-items="DriverIdList" class="form-control">
  <option value="">-- please select --</option>
</select>
```

Note the `value=""`, without this attribute modelbinding will fail to bind to a nullable int.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the asp-for tag helper with a SelectListItem list

Then this is what you write in your form in the view

```
<select asp-for="(Whatever the value is associated to)" asp-items="The List<SelectListItem> list">
    <option disabled selected>---Select---</option> 
<!-- This line will go to the top of the dropdown list -->
</select>
```

This will create a dropdown list where by default nothing is selected and this default value will be null

You can also refer to this other post on stack overflow:

[Set Default/Null Value with Select TagHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845786/set-default-null-value-with-select-taghelper)