# MVC Razor drop down list default value is not triggering onchange event

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a drop down list in c# MVC Razor application that is populated via enum data model object.  My issue comes into play when the user selects the drop down the default value is the first value from the model and when it is selected the onchange event is not being triggered.  Please see code below:

.net core mvc razor view

```
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a id="GenderLnk" href="#">Click Here to Update</a><br>
                    <div id="GenderDiv" style="display:none;">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateGender", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StudentGender, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender))), new { @class = "show", onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
                        }
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Here is the model property

```
    public Gender StudentGender { get; set; }

    public enum Gender
    {
        Female,
        Male,
        [Display(Name ="Not Applicable")]
        NotApplicable,
        Transgender

    }
```

[image: This is screenshot of drop down list with code suggested by Dilan. As can see, still Female is default]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for not triggering the "onChange" function is, it technically does not change  any value in the form if user selected the default value in the first attempt. What you can do is provide a value like "please select" as the default value and let the user choose a value in the list.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StudentGender, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender))), "-- Please Select -- ", new { @class = "show", onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
```

May be you can use this question + answer into consideration as well. Hope this helps.

[Get a default NULL value from DropDownList in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632291/get-a-default-null-value-from-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Hi Dilan,  I have tried this but the default value is still not "-- Please Select ---" when i click the drop down menu.  This "Please Select" value is inserted at the top of the drop down list but the default value is Female still.  I added screenshot to original question

Comment: After playing around with the code some more and referring to the link you posted I was able to get the default option to behave as expected.  I just needed to make the StudentGender object nullable as expressed in the answer in the link you posted.  Thank you!